# Why is this matrix not a reflection in a plane matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, reflection

$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    -1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & -1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & -1 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

This matrix clearly has det -1 and is orthogonal. Why is it not reflection in a plane matrix?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. You should provide more information. For instance, what troubles you in the question ? What have you tried (examples, counter-examples) to find the answer yourself and that didn't work ? Main principle in the community : show your work.

Comment: Remember that the points in a plane are invariant under the reflection induced by it.

Answer (score 1):

In your definition of a reflection of $\mathbb{R}^3$, you have to replace your condition $\det = -1$ by a condition about the dimensions of the eigenspaces $E_1$ and $E_{-1}$ associated to the eigenvalues $1$ and $-1$, namely that $\dim E_1=2$ and $\dim E_{-1}=1$ (note that this condition automatically implies that your determinant is $-1$). Here we clearly have that $\dim E_{-1}=3$.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to see that this matrix corresponds to the reflection through the origin $(0,0,0)$ hence the origin is the only invariant point of this tranformation.